# alignItems not working correctly. React Native flexbox yoga

Tags: ios, react-native, flexbox

Here is the code example: Expected behavior is that it should show a view with a green background. When `alignItems: 'center'` is set on the container, the view with a green background is not shown. Removing `alignItems: 'center'` from the container style shows green view. Can someone explain why it's working like that, and is that not a bug in layout system? Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:'green'}}>
       </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is the default behavior.

`alignItems` default value is `stretch`, which makes the flex item *stretch* along its parent's cross axis, which for `column` direction is the width, the default in React Native.

So when you change that to `center`, it start behaves like an inline element, and collapse to its content, or else `center` can't *center* it, if it still would have *full width*.

Answer (score 1):

By putting style alignItems as `center`, parent view don't provide width and inner view take width based on content. If you want fully background green. you can also set background directly on parent view and no need child view.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  }
});
```